# JavaScript function set to repeat using setTimeout() doesn't callback correctly after it finishes looping

Tags: javascript, canvas, callback, settimeout

I've been working on a project in JavaScript recently and I've hit a bit of a roadblock. I've set up two different animations, one named DarkWaves, and the other one named clearScreen. I want to be able to pass DarkWaves a function(clearScreen, for example), have DarkWaves do its thing, then have DarkWaves call the the function that was passed to it. Unfortunately, I can't get this to work. Some testing reveals that I can't get a callback to work correctly after putting a setTimeout(nameOfTheFunctionThisCodeIsIn, 50) in there. The error that I get is: callback is not a function. I've tried printing the typeof callback too, to no avail: I just get defined, unless I put it in a function without a setTimeout(nameOfThe... I'm sure this is all rather difficult to understand without my code, so I'll stick the relevant bits in here:

```
function DarkWaves(callback){//Dark Wave!

function advancingTriangle(whereToGo, rbgValuez){
    ctx.fillStyle = rbgValuez;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, whereToGo*50);
    ctx.lineTo(whereToGo*50, 0);
    ctx.fill();
    }

if(waveCount === 0){
    $('#rightSideBarOuter').hide();//These just clear out some HTML 
    $('#mainAreaOuter').hide();//    elements I have over my canvas so that the wave can swim through
}

if(waveCount < 30)advancingTriangle(waveCount, 'rgb(0, 0, 0)');
if(waveCount > 15 && waveCount < 45)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 15, 'rgb(40, 40, 40)');
if(waveCount > 30 && waveCount < 60)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 30, 'rgb(80, 80, 80)');
if(waveCount > 45 && waveCount < 75)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 45, 'rgb(120, 120, 120)');
if(waveCount > 60 && waveCount < 90)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 60, 'rgb(160, 160, 160)');
if(waveCount > 75 && waveCount < 105)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 75, 'rgb(200, 200, 200)');
if(waveCount > 90 && waveCount < 120)advancingTriangle(waveCount - 90, 'rgb(240, 240, 240)');

waveCount++;

if(waveCount > 120)waveCount = 0;

if(waveCount !== 0)setTimeout(DarkWaves, 50);
else{callback()}
}
```

I've set up a bit of a temporary fix, which waits 6500 seconds, and then calls the function that I want to call at the end of DarkWaves. Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout(DarkWaves, 50);` doesn't pass `callback` along to the next call of `DarkWaves`, so the callback is lost.

You'd need to pass it:

```
setTimeout(function() { DarkWaves(callback); }, 50);
```

E.g.:

```
if (waveCount !== 0) {
    setTimeout(function() { DarkWaves(callback); }, 50);
} else{
    callback();
}
```

Or using `Function#bind`:

```
if (waveCount !== 0) {
    setTimeout(DarkWaves.bind(this, callback), 50);
} else{
    callback();
}
```

That's slightly more lightweight.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks alot! I can't believe that I didn't see that earlier. Why do you have to make an anonymous function in the set timeout, as opposed to just doing setTimeout(DarkWaves(callback), 50); I tried doing that, and it didn't work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @DefecateRainbows: `setTimeout(DarkWaves(callback), 50);` **calls** `DarkWaves(callback)` and passes its return value into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`. You don't want to call it at that point, you want to schedule a function that *will* call it when the timeout occurs.

Comment: @DefecateRainbows: No worries. Another option would be `setTimeout(DarkWaves.bind(this, callback), 50);` And in fact, that might be slightly better.